# Derivatives in worded problems

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have encountered a question in calculus that goes like this:

A manufacturer of athletic footwear finds that the sales of their ZipStride brand running shoes is a function $f(p)$ of the selling price $p$ (in dollars) for a pair of shoes. Suppose that $f(120) = 9000$ pairs of shoes and $f'(120) = −60$ pairs of shoes per dollar. The revenue that the manufacturer will receive for selling $f(p)$ pairs of shoes at $p$ dollars per pair is $R(p) = p \cdot f(p)$. Find $R'(120)$. What impact would a small increase in price have on the manufacturer’s revenue?

My question is what do $f'(p)$ and $R'(p)$ signify? I know that they are slopes of a tangent line at certain points or the derivatives but in this problem, what are their significance? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Try unit analysis

Answer (score 2):

When you increase the price of a pair of shoes, you will sell less pairs. You might now ask: how many less pairs do I sell when I increase the price from 120 to 121 dollars? This is what $f'(120)$ tells you,  i.e. you will sell $f'(120)=-60$ shoes less (pedantically, we have to say -60 shoes more, which is 60 shoes less).

On the other hand, you earn money by selling shoes, and you now might want to ask the question if you would earn more money or less by increasing the price from 120 to 121? This is what $R'(120)$ denotes (precisely, it tells you how much more or less money you make by increasing the price by 1 dollar). The answer to this question is non-trivial: on the one hand,  you will earn one dollar more per sold shoe, on the other hand you will sell less shoes.

Likely, you don't care how many shoes you sell, but only care how much money you make by selling shoes. In this case, you should increase the price if $R'(x)$ is greater than zero, and decrease the price if $R'(x)$ is smaller than zero. Under certain assumptions, there is then this sweet spot where the price is just optimal (in the sense that it maximizes your profit), and this occurs when $R'(x)$ is exactly zero (there are some additional requirements since $R'(x)=0$ could also indicate a local minimum of your profits, but that's a different story).